# Redirecting output issues when creating child process. Writing own Shell in POSIX

Tags: c, linux, shell, process, io-redirection

I am trying to redirect the output but I have 2 issues. Issue 1: ls -l > file works fine, but if I do cat file1 > file2, my shell seems to be working indefinitely in the background. I have to interrupt it (Ctrl-D) after 2 to 3 min of wait.
issue 2:  Same problem when using sort < fruits, my shell seems to wait for a process to finish, but it never does. So I have to interrupt it. I know I am not doing something right, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong/missing. I have not implemented the pipe yet.  Your help will be appreciated.

```
int create_childprocess(char *argv[], int argc)
{

    //int pid;

    int fd, i, ret;

    pid_t pid;


    int redirect_sign =0;

    if((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        /*error exit -fork failed*/
        perror("Fork failed");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        /*this is the child*/
        printf("\nThis is the child ready to execute: %s\n", argv[0]);

        for(i=0; i<argc; i++)  
        {

            if((strcmp(">", argv[i])) ==0)
                redirect_sign=1;

            else if((strcmp(">>", argv[i])) ==0)
                redirect_sign=2; 

            else if((strcmp("<", argv[i])) ==0)
                redirect_sign=3;

             else if((strcmp("<<", argv[i])) ==0)
                redirect_sign=4;  

        }   

        if (redirect_sign==1)  //if ">" is found...
        {

            fd = open(argv[argc-1],O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0755);
            if(fd == -1)
            {   
                /*An error occured. Print an error message and bail.*/
                perror("open");
                exit(-1);   
            }   
            else
            {
                printf("Writing output of the command %s to file created\n", argv[0]);
                dup2(fd,1);

                execlp(argv[0], argv[0], NULL);
                close(fd);

            }


        }
        else if (redirect_sign==2)  //if ">>" was found...
        {
            fd = open(argv[argc-1], O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0755);
            if(fd == -1)
            {   
                /*An error occured. Print an error message and bail.*/
                perror("open");
                exit(-1);   
            }   
            else
            {
                printf("Appending output of the command %s to file created\n", argv[0]);
                dup2(fd,1);

                execlp(argv[0], argv[0], NULL);
                close(fd);  
            }
        }
        else if (redirect_sign==3)  //if "<" was found...
        {
            fd = open(argv[argc-1], O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0755);
            if(fd == -1)
            {   
                /*An error occured. Print an error message and bail.*/
                perror("open");
                exit(-1);   
            }   
            else
            {
                printf("Writing content of file %s to disk\n", argv[argc-1]);
                dup2(fd,1);

                execlp(argv[0], argv[0], NULL);
                close(fd);  
            }
        }
        else if (redirect_sign==4)  //if "<" was found...
        {
            fd = open(argv[argc-1], O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0755);
            if(fd == -1)
            {   
                /*An error occured. Print an error message and bail.*/
                perror("open");
                exit(-1);   
            }   
            else
            {
                printf("Writing content of file %s to %s \n", argv[argc-1], argv[0] );
                dup2(fd,1);


                execlp(argv[0], argv[0], NULL);
                close(fd);  
            }
        }
        else  //if ">" or ">>" or "<" or "<<" was not found 
        {
            execvp(argv[0], &argv[0]);

            /*error exit - exec returned*/
            perror("Exec returned");
            exit(-1);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        /*this is the parent -- wait for child to terminate*/
        wait(pid,0,0);
        printf("\nThe parent is exiting now\n");
    }

    free (argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might consider reading `man execlp()` again, especially on the way how to pass arguments. Or perhaps rethink about using `execvp()`.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking too closely at your code, you are probably not closing a file descriptor.  In particular, you definitely want to `close(fd)` before you call `execlp`, and be very careful that you've closed all other relevant file descriptors in any pipes you have created.  Correcting this particular error and closing the output file is not likely to fix your problem;  more likely there is an error in the code you are not showing and you've left some pipes open so that `cat` is waiting for an EOF that will never come because it has the write side of a pipe open, and the read side of that pipe is its own stdin.

Comment: @ William Pursell, all the file descriptors were closed, however, I was not closing them before the execlp. Now, cat file1 > file2 works fine. But I still have the issue #2 with the input coming from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using dup2(fd,1); in all situations. I think that for input (stdin), you want to replace file descriptor 0 (or the predefined macro STDIN_FILENO.

Comment: @ fredvanl, I keep getting the error message: "Bad file descriptor" if I change the file descriptor from 1 to STDIN_FILENO (or 0).

Comment: In that case it is probably time to start implementing the real piping part of the code and start filling up the pipe so that the process can actually read it. William already made a note on that.